# How to load Google Analytics and Facebook SDK in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, facebook-sdk-3.0, kango-framework

I'm developing a chrome extension using Kango framework, and I waned to use both Google Analytics and facebook SDK. I edited the manifest file to include the follwoign

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self'; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' chrome-extension-resource: https://*.facebook.net https://*.facebook.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' chrome-extension-resource: https://*.facebook.net https://*.facebook.com; frame-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' chrome-extension-resource: https://*.facebook.net https://*.facebook.com"
```

But it doesn't work! and I'm getting the following error

```
Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://connect.facebook.net".
```

Comment: I wonder how much more descriptive an error message could be. The next level is probably self-correcting errors... :)

Comment: @Fattah, I am about to create some plugins and looking for some best framework for developing cross-browser extensions. I found Kango-framework. Can this framework flexible and good enough to create cross-browser extensions. Can you suggest some good framework and libraries to start building cross-browser extensions.

Comment: @Mahi Oh man! That was six years ago :) ... As far as I remember, Kango was doing the job correctly. I just checked their website, and the last update was two years ago, and I assume the browsers did a lot of changes since then. You can give it a try!

Answer (score 3):

Change the `script-src` directive to have `'unsafe-eval'` at the end.

```
script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://connect.facebook.net 'unsafe-eval';
```

Note that this will lower the security of your extension as random strings of JavaScript can be executed.