# Define the right content_security_policy for facebook share button on chrome extensions

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, share-button

I'm trying to add Facebook share button to my chrome extension (popup.html), but it's not easy to do so because of the CSP.

I know i can define "content_security_policy" in my manifest.js, but i couldn't find the right way.

I didn't find an answer on Google or on [Stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)

[this answer didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645651/how-to-load-google-analytics-and-facebook-sdk-in-chrome-extension)

Any suggestion?